# How to convert NSManagedObject to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to convert `NSManagedObject` to `NSDictionary` this is what I tried:

```
var keys:NSArray = order?.entity.attributesByName.keys
var dict:NSDictionary = order?.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys)
```

But I get error:

```
 LazyForwardCollection<MapCollectionView<Dictionary<NSObject,
 AnyObject>, NSObject>>? is not convertible to NSArray.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you need exactly `NSDictionary` or it's ok if you get swift Dictionary?

Comment: I don't know. My goal is to convert that dictionary to JSON string. So if I can do that with dictionary I don't have a problem with that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `keys` property of a dictionary returns a `LazyForwardCollection` which has to be converted to a real array.

Another problem is that `order` is apparently an optional, so it needs
to be unwrapped, e.g. with optional binding.

```
if let theOrder = order {
    let keys = Array(theOrder.entity.attributesByName.keys)
    let dict = theOrder.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys)
} else {
    // order is nil
}
```

Comment: I don't know. I am using swift 1.2. It require from me to add parameter name but second line can't pass: `let keys = Array(arrayLiteral: order?.entity.attributesByName.keys)
        let dict = order?.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys)`

Comment: @1110: I don't have access to Xcode 6.3 currently, so I tested it with 6.2. I did not expect a difference for this code, but that may be wrong. I can check with Xcode 6.3 later. Sorry if that caused confusion.

Comment: Yes I copied it but it doesn't work. I don't understand this should be very simple thing :(

Comment: @1110: See updated answer (now checked with Xcode 6.3/Swift 1.2).

Comment: @MartinR Even though this works, I can't still serialise them to Json, NSJsonSerialization.isValidObject still returns false. Any ideas? Did you get this to work ultimately?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the objects out of the database as `NSManagedObject`s, you could  set the `resultType`, on your `NSFetchRequest`, to `DictionaryResultType` to have Dictionaries returned when you execute the request.

However, you will not be able to edit values in these dictionaries and have the changes saved in your database. If you just need to read from your database, then that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant but this should work...

```
var names = Array<String>()
for attributeName in order?.entity.attributesByName.keys
{
    names.append(attributeName as! String)
}
```

This is a problem of converting some kind of collection to another, which is never trivial even if internal types are same.

edit : 
little more swift spirit

```
var names = map(order?.entity.attributesByName.keys){return $0 as! String}
```