# Converting an NSmanagedObject to NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdictionary, nsmanagedobject

Working with MultipeerConnectivity I need to pass a `NSDictionary` via discoveryInfo to another device. All my data is saved in CoreData as ManagedObjects.

I have a Person entity, which has several houses as attributes.

How can I convert such a `ManagedObject` into a `NSDictionary` working with the Swift Language.

I saw somebody working with this Objective c code, but myself I am not familiar with Objective C, so I don't know if this is the right way to go.

```
NSArray *keys = [[[myObject entity] attributesByName] allKeys];

NSDictionary *dict = [myObject dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

and when you want to restore it you set the values of your managedObject like this:

```
[myObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dict];
```

I am trying to learn understanding Objective c, maybe you could confirm if this is the right code in Swift and the right way to reach the goal:

```
var keys:NSArray = myObject.entity.attributesByName.allKeys
var dict:NSDictionary = myObject.dictionaryWithValuesForKeys(keys)
myObject.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dict)
```

Comment: Did you try the code? Does it compile? Does it produce the expected result? If not, what do you get?

Comment: Yes, three errors: NSArray' is not implicitly convertible to '[AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?
'NSDictionary' is not implicitly convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert? [NSObject : AnyObject]' does not have a member named 'allKeys'

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29667848/1187415