# Could not cast value of type 'NSKnownKeysDictionary1' () to '' ()

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm attempting to convert my *NSManagedObject* into a *Dictionary* so I can use serialize it for *JSON*.

```
func fetchRecord() -> [Record] {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Record>(entityName:"Record")
        let context = PersistenceService.context

        fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

        do {
            records = try context.fetch(Record.fetchRequest())

        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from CoreData")
        }
        print(records)
        return records
 }
```

I have loked at this question: [How to convert NSManagedObject to NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667202/how-to-convert-nsmanagedobject-to-nsdictionary) but their method appears very different to mine. I have also attempted the methods provided in this question: [CoreData object to JSON in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237755/coredata-object-to-json-in-swift-3/46268149#46268149). However I am receiving this error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSKnownKeysDictionary1' (0x108fbcaf8) to 'iOSTest01.Record' (0x1081cd690)$

and I can't seem to find the solution.

The error has been mentioned before here: [Core Data: Could not cast value of type 'MyType_MyType_2' to MyType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048458/core-data-could-not-cast-value-of-type-mytype-mytype-2-to-mytype) but none of the methods are resolving my issue. Could anyone provide me a *Swift* solution for this?

**Update**

To help the comment below I have added the following:

```
var record: Record!
var records = [Record]()
```

Record+CoreDataClass:

```
public class Record: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Record+CoreDataProperties:

```
extension Record {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Record> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Record>(entityName: "Record")
    }

    @NSManaged public var name: String?

}
```

This is where `records` are defined.

Comment: Where is `records` defined and how? – With `resultType = .dictionaryResultType` the fetch request returns an array of *dictionaries,* that is incompatible with your return type `[Record]`.

Comment: Please see my update on the question.

Comment: Do you want an array of Record objects or an array of dictionaries?

Comment: I believe I need an array of dictionaries in order to serialize them to JSON? I may be wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to get an array of *dictionaries* from the fetch request
you must do two things:

- Set `fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType` (as you already did), and
- declare the fetch request as `NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>` instead of `NSFetchRequest<YourEntity>`.

Example:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName:"Event")
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType

// Optionally, to get only specific properties:
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [ "prop1", "prop2" ]

do {
    let records = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    print(records)
} catch {
    print("Core Data fetch failed:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Now `records` has the type `[NSDictionary]` and will contain an
array with dictionary representations of the fetched objects.

Comment: Thank you for this, my data is now printing out as a Dictionary. However it has altered how I display my data now as it is no longer using the `Record` class instead it's using a `NSDictionary`. What is the best approach to get my data to display as before?

Comment: @Chace: I would use separate fetch requests. One (with an NSFetchedResultsController) to display the data in a table view, and another one for exporting the data.

Comment: Nice explanation. Saved my day, or should I say "evening". Thank you :)